# Simple javascript viewer for ArcGIS Server data

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, web-mapping

I would like a simple javascript viewer which will allow end users to do the following in their browser:

- Add layers from arcgis server by clicking an "add data" button
- See attributes with an info tool or table veiw
- Measure distances and areas
- Draw points, lines, polygons
- Save the state of their map for viewing later

Is there a javascript template for ESRI javascript API that can do this?
Basically I want a local copy of the ArcGIS online viewer for users to access our internal ArcGIS Server data.
Everything I have found references ArcGIS Online, and not a local Arcgis Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a good one here: https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI.

Click here to [View Live app](http://davidspriggs.github.io/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI/viewer/).
Includes:

- Growler
- Draw
- Geolocation
- Advanced
- Print
- Help
- Measure
- Directions
- Editor
- Scalebar
- Bookmarks

Another one is in another answer, Esri CIS did a great work developing such an application. Pity it is in Russian.

Most of other apps I've seen tend to be more ArcGIS Online specific: [here](https://github.com/benheb/ArcGIS-Online-Templates/tree/master/templates) you can find some of the templates (some are really good and would cover most of the needs).

Esri has also released a bunch of JS apps with some viewer-like functionality which you could reuse for building own viewer with perhaps a more complete functionality set. These apps can be found at [ArcGIS for Local Government](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.1/index.html#/ArcGIS_for_Local_Government_maps_and_apps/028s0000006t000000/) resource center. Very many of them have a live version to play with and include simple geocode search function, basemap gallery, and print.

Comment: +1 nice find... That is a very nice product he put together..

Comment: I agree, it is a great one. I remember also customizing a really good JS viewer for 5 years ago http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15987. Not supported any longer, but was a good one too

Comment: Yes, I worked with that one too. GitHub is getting to be a place you need to search and browse often to see what is being shared...

Comment: Looks good, how would I go about adding an 'Add/Remove Layers" function?

Answer (score 1):

What about "Viewer from Esri CIS", we don't plan to translate it into English now.
May be we will do in future. First we must be sure that russian and CIS customers use it and this is something they need.

Ivan, Esri Russia and CIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Viewer for ArcGIS from Esri CIS:
https://github.com/ESRI-CIS/jsviewer

Comment: Thanks, Anybody know of something similar in English?

Comment: Oh, my fault. I thought there is some sort of "readme" in English. I'll ask developers to make English description.